# Accpac import orders with vb

Tags: database, insert-update, accpac

I'm attempting to import orders into accpac.

I've encountered a snag. 
I have a macro(avb) that I've used in the past to import Items, PO's and receipts. So I'm not strictly a virgin. 
The code is written to be portable and when given the correct XML template file it imports perfectly, and spits out a report file.

To generate the template file I do a manual import of one file and record the script.

Now when I run it for orders the record isn't imported.

Here's my report.

```
<AccpacImpExp Status="161"/>  
Internal error. Must compose with Order Header.
Internal error. Must compose with Order Header.
Failed to insert record
Stopped processing at record 0 in Orders.
```

Now I have a couple questions.

1. What does this mean?
2. Why does this
   not happen when I do the manual import?
3. How can I find the answers to these questions without posting
   on a forum?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the orders lies outside the norm. They will not be imported in the same manner as the rest of the modules. 
I was forced to import the orders by recording a macro while I entered an order manually.

That this is acceptable is one solid reason to loath the AccPac product. It weakens it's developers, and makes them complacent.

On a side. It seems Returns suffers the same sickness. One can export from it easily, but not import. Sickening.